# inputNumber does not work i.e. allows alphabets

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 7.0.  Im trying to use p:inputNumber as

```
<p:inputNumber id="test" value="#{bean.doubleValue}" decimalPlaces="2" />
```

but this does not restrict this input only to numbers but it also allows alphabets etc.

Comment: I don't see that happening with 10. You could upgrade or add https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/keyFilter.xhtml

Comment: what do u mean, should i upgrade to primefaces 10??

Comment: also keyfilter does all except restricting decimal places

Comment: KeyFilter does what you configure it to do.

Comment: Even in 7.0 PF InputNumber did not allow alpha characters so can you check your F12 Console. i feel like JS code is not loading and you are actually getting an error preventing InputNumber from truly being an Input Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Melloware, I got this question resolved by writing a function in js and calling it in inputText.  The code is as follows:-

```
<p:inputText id="inp2" value="#{bean.Ctrl}" onkeypress="return keyPressCheck(event.which, this.value, #{bean.CtrlType});" maxlength="#{bean.CtrlML}" />
```

and JS Function which is doing marvellous is

```
function keyPressCheck (kp, cv, isN) {
    if (isN==1) {
        if (kp === 46) {
            if (cv.indexOf(".")===-1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (kp < 48) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (kp > 57) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```